# Tracking what data has changed since some time

Tags: postgresql

In our application we have a central database and many disconnected client applications with their own local databases. A client connects to the central server and the server should send them the data that have changed since the client's last connection.

Because there are too many clients, and some of them might cease to exist without notifying the server, it is not practical to keep the pending changes on the server per client.

That is why in every relevant table we have a column `update_date` that is on every insert and every update set to the `current_timestamp`. Deletes are handled in a similar way, with an auxiliary table for every synchronized table, where we store the primary key of the synchronized table and the `delete_date`.

When a client connects to the server, it sends to the server the last synchronization timestamp, the server sends all changes where `update_date > last_sync` and then the `current_timestamp` of the transaction to store on the client as the `last_sync`.

The problem of this approach is that when there is a running transaction `T1` with the `current_timestamp` = 1000, the client connects in a transaction `T2` with the `current_timestamp` = 2000. Since `T2` does not see the not yet committed changes made in `T1`, their are not sent to the client. The next time when the client connects, the changes from `T1` are already committed, but they are marked with `update_date` = 1000, so they will not be sent the client requesting the changes made after 2000.

Any suggestions how to make sure that the clients get all the changed records? It is acceptable that the clients gets the same changes multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go for an audit trigger to solve this which is described here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger

After that you can choose how to apply the updates (or ignore some of them if they're not relevant).

---

Alternatively you could try one of the standard replication modules, some of the asynchronous ones should do the trick: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Comparison_matrix

[Bucardo](https://bucardo.org/) for example was specifically designed for cases like these.

Comment: Thanks Wolph, I think the audit triggers would be a bit of overkill, since I need to send to the client just the current values, not the full history. Also, I am not sure it would solve my problem of skipping some changes done in a transaction isolated at the time of the previous synchronization. 

I will have a look at Bucardo. I have previously not looked into replication solutions, because the clients don't use PostgreSql and there are just too many of them.

Comment: Well, in that case you could change your transaction isolation level so every client always sees the latest data. Or even use for-read locks when reading data.

Comment: I have tought about the transaction isolation level. The problem is that then I might send to clients data from transactions that will be later rolled back. My current "solution" is to send to the client all changes since `last_sync - 5 minutes`, assuming that transactions will not be longer than 5 minutes. The clients have no problem with getting the data multiple times, it is just a bit less efficient. The read locks would probably affect the performance of the main server application too much, but I test that.

Comment: Do note that you should only lock the rows you are actually planning on changing, that makes it better perhaps. Audit triggers can make things easier though, you can just replay the entire transaction log and you can decide on the client which you want to keep.

Comment: I have tried to add the read locks in the modifying transactions, but realized that I'd need to touch too many places in the application. Sending the entire transaction log or the entire content of the tables is what I want to avoid (except for clients that are connecting for the very first time. After researching a bit, I think I have come up with a better solution that I have in place now and that is simpler than redoing most of the application. My task is to let the client know a timestamp, before which no further changes in the database will appear. Because of the transaction isolation...

Comment: ... I cannot use the `current_timestamp`. But I think I can use the `pg_stat_activity` to check the minimal start time of the currently running transactions. So my "solution" is to use for the `sync_time` the following query: `select min(xact_start)
from pg_stat_activity
where xact_start is not null 
      and state in ('active', 'idle in transaction') 
      and datname = 'mydb';`